# Send Automatic Email for loop

Tags: vba, email

I have a code:

```
Sub sendEmail()
  Dim OutlookApp As Object
  Dim OutlookItem As Object
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim Address As String

  Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set OutlookItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

  With OutlookItem
    For i = 4 To 15
      If Cells(i, 18) <= Cells(i, 6) Then
        Address = Cells(i, 14).Value
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
        Set OutlookItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

        .To = Address
        .Subject = "Calibration Due Soon !!!"
        .Body = "Reminder: Calibration of " & Cells(i, 4) & "is due on " & Cells(i, 9)
        .Send

        Set OutlookItem = Nothing
        Set OutlookApp = Nothing

        'Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:08 AM#)
      ElseIf Cells(i, 18) > Cells(i, 15) Then
        Exit Sub
      ElseIf Cells(i, 18) = "" And Cells(i, 15) = "" Then
        Exit Sub
      End If
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

It does send only first email then it prompts me with run-time error saying :

> The item has been moved or deleted

And debugger highlights the " .To = Address" line.
When I use .Display instead of send it works.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you set the Outlook app to Nothing *inside the loop*? That's horribly inefficient, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Re-creating the Outlook application object in every loop iteration does not make sense. It's equivalent to killing Outlook and re-starting it for every mail you send. Let's not do that.

First, set a reference to the "Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library" in your Excel VBA project (or whatever version you happen to have installed).

Now you can create an Outlook object directly with `New` and it also enables the autocompletion and all the Outlook-specific constants, like `olMailItem`.

Now your code can be condensed to something like this:

```
Sub sendEmail()
  Dim OutlookApp As New Outlook.Application
  Dim r As Range

  For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("4:15").Rows
    If r.Cells(18) <= r.Cells(6) And r.Cells(18) > "" And r.Cells(15) > "" Then
      With OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        .To = r.Cells(14)
        .Subject = "Calibration Due Soon !!!"
        .Body = "Reminder: Calibration of " & r.Cells(4) & " is due on " & r.Cells(9)
        .Send
      End With
    End If
  Next r

  OutlookApp.Quit
  Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```